# NPM Versión diferente a la actual en Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, nodejs, npm

Acabo de crear un proyecto de **Laravel 5.5** en Ubuntu 16.04. Mirando [éste video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zn9H4YUqvZA) pude actualizar Bootstrap de **3.3.7** a **4.0.0-beta.2**.

Es un servidor "Shared hosting" con Plesk 17 Onyx, por las dudas.

Tengo el siguiente error al correr `npm run dev`:

```
usuario@host:~/subdominio$ npm run dev

> @ dev /var/www/vhosts/dominio/subdominio
> npm run development

ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.2.6
Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has
a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least 4.7.0 to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at  https://nodejs.org/

npm ERR! Linux 4.9.50-x86_64-linode86
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'npm run development'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run development
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/vhosts/dominio/subdominio/npm-debug.log
```

Lo raro es que cuando corro `npm install` con otro usuario que sí es sudoer me aparece versión 5.5.1

```
usuario@host:~/subdominio$ npm install
npm WARN prefer global npm@5.5.1 should be installed with -g
/var/www/vhosts/dominio/subdominio
├── abbrev@1.1.1
├── ansi-regex@3.0.0
├── aproba@1.2.0
├── bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2  extraneous
├─┬ cacache@9.2.9
│ └── lru-cache@4.1.1
├── cli-table2@0.2.0
├─┬ cross-env@5.1.0
│ └─┬ cross-spawn@5.1.0
│   ├── lru-cache@4.1.1
│   └── which@1.3.0
├── detect-indent@5.0.0
├── glob@7.1.2
├── hosted-git-info@2.5.0
├── is-cidr@1.0.0
├── JSONStream@1.3.1
├─┬ laravel-mix@1.5.1
│ ├─┬ babel-preset-env@1.6.1
│ │ └── semver@5.4.1
│ ├─┬ chokidar@1.7.0
│ │ └─┬ readdirp@2.1.0
│ │   └── readable-stream@2.3.3
│ ├── glob@7.1.2
│ ├─┬ node-sass@4.5.3
│ │ ├─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │ │ └─┬ normalize-package-data@2.4.0
│ │ │   └── hosted-git-info@2.5.0
│ │ ├─┬ node-gyp@3.6.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ nopt@3.0.6
│ │ │ │ └── abbrev@1.1.1
│ │ │ └── rimraf@2.6.2
│ │ ├─┬ npmlog@4.1.2
│ │ │ └─┬ gauge@2.7.4
│ │ │   └── aproba@1.2.0
│ │ └─┬ request@2.83.0
│ │   ├── safe-buffer@5.1.1
│ │   └── uuid@3.1.0
│ └─┬ yargs@8.0.2
│   └─┬ string-width@2.1.1
│     └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0
│       └── ansi-regex@3.0.0
├── libnpx@9.6.0
├── lru-cache@4.1.1
├── meant@1.0.1
├── node-gyp@3.6.2
├── normalize-package-data@2.4.0
├── npm@5.5.1  extraneous                <- acá
├── npm-lifecycle@1.0.3
├── npm-package-arg@5.1.2
├── npm-packlist@1.1.9
├── npm-profile@2.0.4
├── npm-registry-client@8.5.0
├── npm-user-validate@1.0.0
```

...

Entonces no entiendo cuál tengo instalado, y por qué funciona mal. Agradezco cualquier opinión, sugerencia, etc.

Comment: Tienes node v4.2.6 y npm v5.5.1. Versiones distintas para programas distintos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te pasa es que tienes node 4.2.6 y al parecer está rota, lo que te aconsejo es que instales NVM (Node version manager) para poder usar miltiples versiones de node, sin que interfiera una con otra, de esta forma:

Vía curl:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash
```

Vía wget:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash
```

Si ves algún error al final de la instalación usar:

```
command -v nvm
```

Posteriormente instalado nvm puedes instalar cualquier version de node usando:

```
nvm install v4.7 // donde deberias cambiar la version a V.4.7 o algo similar
```

Luego para switchearte entre versiones de node usar:

```
nvm use v4.7
```

Y debería funcionarte. De lo contrario te tocará hacer una actualización del node o en su defecto desinstalarlo y volverlo a instalar que por lo general no me gusta mucho.

Comment: Hice eso con el usuario sudoer, pero con el usuario no sudoer, sigo viendo la versión 3.5.2 además de que no puedo ejecutar nvm

Comment: @Maramal si instalaste nvm no importa, ejecuta el comando de nvm sin sudo y debe de funcionar, de hecho, mientras respondía la pregunta lo instalé en mi ubuntu siguiendo estos pasos.

Comment: Seguí tus pasos, listé con `nvm ls` y me aparece correctamente `node -> stable (-> v5.5.0) (default)`. Pero en el otro usuario, me sigue apareciendo la misma versión como venía diciendo.

Comment: @Maramal ese punto lo desconozco, porque no me ha tocado hacerlo. lo mas que puedo hacer por ti es pasarte este link, https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1533